# Checking if a checkbox has been checked in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I have a strongly typed ViewModel which contains check boxes.

When I am processing in my Controller for an update, **I need to find out whether the item has been checked or not.**

How do I go about doing that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Update(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    var isChecked = viewModel.ThePropertyUsedWithYourCheckBoxFor;
}
```

Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I added a boolean column in my model to take care of this... if (template.IsChecked == true)